# How two Avoid overlapping of ImageViews in Dynamic creation at random positions in android

Tags: android

i am new to android and i am trying to create 50 images dynamically in my activity at random locations using random function. The problem is on the creation of these images they seems to overlap sometimes, can anyone guide me how to avoid those overlapping in dynamic creation, due to my requirement i don't want to do this image view creation via XML.

```
for (int i = 0; i<30/*R.nextInt(10-4)+4*/; i ++) 
        {
            Random r = new Random();
            posX=r.nextInt((displaywidth)-(displaywidth-500))+(displaywidth-500);
            posY=r.nextInt((displayheight)-(displayheight-500))+(displayheight-500);
            if(pPosX!=posX&&pPosY!=posY)
            {
                if(posX<=displaywidth&&posY<=displayheight)
                {
                    System.out.println("XX "+posX+" X "+pPosX+" W "+displaywidth);
                    System.out.println("YY "+posY+" Y "+pPosY+" H "+displayheight);
                    image[i] = new ImageView(this);
                    PicID=r.nextInt(pic.length)-1;
                    if(PicID==-1)
                    {
                        PicID++;
                    }
                    image[i].setImageResource(pic[PicID]);
                    image[i].setTag(PicID);
                    int tag = (Integer) image[i].getTag();
                    System.out.println("PicTagTask"+tag);
                    image[i].setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(50,50));
                    image[i].setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER);
                    image[i].setPadding(1,1,1,1);   
                    image[i].setX(posX);
                    image[i].setY(posY);
                    image[i].setAdjustViewBounds(true);
                    image[i].startAnimation(animation[R.nextInt(4)]/*animScale*/);
                    image[i].setOnTouchListener(this);
                    System.out.println("ImageViewID ="+image[i].getId());
                    mainlayout.addView(image[i]);

                    pPosX=posX;
                    pPosY=posY;
                    passTagImage[i]=PicID;

                }`enter code here`
```

Comment: can u post u code ? so that we can get clear idea about what is going wrong .

Comment: you can use **weight** for your imageview